# How to write unit test case for code inside catch block c# in XUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

As below code I have few logic written in catch block and for that I have to write unit test.

**Code**

```
try
{
    var localResults = await _repository.GetData(Key).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return localResults;
}
catch (EntityNotFoundException)
{
    var results = await _adapter.GetData(Key).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return results;
}
```

when I am trying to setup repository to return exception by below code it is not working as expected.

```
_repository.Setup(x => x.GetData(It.IsAny<key>())).Throws(new EntityNotFoundException());
```

Comment: Can you please provide a minimum reproducible example

Comment: Is there any specific requirement to write test case inside catch block? As per my view all exception should be handled at original code.